# @ViewChild not working for <tabset> after upgrading to Angular11

Tags: angular

I am upgrading Angular version from 6.2 to 11. After upgrading I am facing issue with @ViewChild(). Its woorking for other scenarios but not working in case of . below I have added file contents.

*tab.component.html*

```
<tabset #reportTabs class="secondary_tabs col-md-12" *ngIf="reportType==='package' && packageorPageId !== undefined ">
        <tab heading="View" [active]="showView" (select)="selectTab(1)">
          <app-report-view #viewtab (fullScreenEvent)="enableFullScreen($event)" [frequency]="docFreq" [packageDocument]="packageDocumentObj" [packageOrPageId]="packageorPageId" [showRVAForm]="showRVAForm" [reportType]="reportType" [asOfDate]="docPED" [viewWarningMessage]="viewWarningMessage" [showRVA]="showRVA"></app-report-view>
        </tab>
        <tab [disabled]="item.value.data.isDeprecated || item?.value?.data?.fileType !== 'pdf' ||(item?.value?.data?.fileType === 'pdf' && !hasStitchPermission) " heading="Stitch" (select)="selectTab(3)">
          <app-stitch #stitchTab [packageId]="packageId" [date]="date" [packageStatus]="packageStatus" [docPED]="docPED"></app-stitch>
        </tab>
        <tab [disabled]="item.value.data.isDeprecated || !item.value.data.manualUploadAllowed || !hasUploadPermission" heading="Upload" (select)="selectTab(2)">
          <p>test Upload tab inside reports tab</p>
          <app-upload #uploadTab [reportType]="reportType" [showRVASelection]="showRVASelection" [hasRVAForm]="hasRVAForm" [packageorPageId]="packageorPageId" [date]="date" [uploadWarningMessage]="uploadWarningMessage" [uploadErrorMessage]="uploadErrorMessage"></app-upload>
        </tab>
 </tabset>
```

*tab.component.ts* file

```
import {TabsetComponent} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {UploadComponent} from '../upload/upload.component';

@ViewChild('uploadTab') uploadTab: UploadComponent;

ngOnInit(){

}

selectTab(tabId: number) {
//some logic
this.rvaApplicable();
//some more logic
}

rvaApplicable() {
   
      this.subscriptions.push(this._dataService.validatePackagePED(this.packageId, this.date, this.date).subscribe(data => {
        this.showRVASelection = data['showRVASelection'];
        this.hasRVAForm = data['hasRVAForm'];
        this.uploadErrorMessage = data['uploadErrorMessage'];
        this.uploadWarningMessage = data['uploadWarningMessage'];
        **this.uploadTab.showRVASelection = data['showRVASelection'];
        this.uploadTab.checkRVASelection();**

      }));
   }
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "portal",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint portal --fix ",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test:watch": "ng test --watch",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "test-coverage": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "test:headless": "ng test --watch=false --karma-config src/karma.phantomjs.conf.js",
    "build:prod": "ng build",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --proxy http://proxy.jpmchase.net:8443 --versions.chrome=2.35",
    "e2e": "ng e2e --webdriver-update false",
    "build:skip": "ng version",
    "build:ssap": "ng build",
    "build:local": "ng build",
    "build:test": "ng build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.txt",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
    "@ct-tuxedo/angular": "5.0.0",
    "@ct-tuxedo/tuxedo-bootstrap": "5.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "8.0.0-beta.4",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^18.0.1",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-split": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "angular-split-ng6": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "deep-extend": "0.6.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-tree": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "5.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "10.0.1",
    "ngx-treeview": "6.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.4",
    "pdfjs-dist": "~2.5.207",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.2.14",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "16.0.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.7",
    "sass": "^1.25.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "**/tar": "^4.4.8",
    "**/adm-zip": "^0.4.9",
    "**/glob-parent": "^3.1.0",
    "**/serialize-javascript": "^1.4.0",
    "**/ssri": "^6.0.1",
    "**/trim-newlines": "^1.0.0",
    "**/ansi-regex": "^4.1.0",
    "**/nth-check": "^2.0.1",
    "**/set-value": "^2.0.1",
    "**/unset-value": "^1.0.0",
    "**/json-schema": "0.4.0",
    "**/ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "**/node-forge": "^0.10.0",
    "**/minimist": "~0.0.1",
    "**/async": "^2.6.4",
    "**/scss-tokenizer": "^0.2.3"
  }
}
```

So basically there is parent child structure between tab and upload component. And now my uploadComponent is not working.
Here rvaApplicable() is the method that calls the child component's method. And this rvaApplicable() is in turn being called from selectTab() which is called from html.

Answer (score 1):

Move your logic to `ngAfterViewInit()` callback

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.uploadTab.fetchUploadDetails();
}
```

Comment: I have edited tab.component.ts file with actual content. Can you please help me now where should I call this.uploadtab.checkRVASelection()